# CGridView limited to 90 records

Tags: yii, yii-components

Yii 1.1.14

When my table holds more than 90 records, CGridView will **fail to load the newest records**. When I delete some records, and bring the total below 90, it will again show me the most recent records.

- **How do I get CGridView to show the newest records?**

My model::search() is almost as out of the box. (Only change: sort descending).

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('xpl',$this->xpl,true);
    $criteria->compare('phpClass',$this->phpClass,true);
    $criteria->compare('line',$this->line);
    $criteria->compare('function',$this->function,true);
    $criteria->compare('usr',$this->usr,true);
    $criteria->compare('guessedName',$this->guessedName,true);
    $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
    $criteria->compare('cls',$this->cls);
    $criteria->compare('vis',$this->vis);
    $criteria->compare('cet',$this->cet,true);
    $criteria->compare('trace',$this->trace,true);
    $criteria->compare('iconID',$this->iconID);
    $criteria->compare('albumID',$this->albumID);
    $criteria->compare('record_created',$this->record_created,true);
    $criteria->compare('timestamp',$this->timestamp);
    $criteria->compare('vrs',$this->vrs,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort'=>array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
                    ),
    ));
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<?php

Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerScriptFile($this->assetsBase.'/js/plug.note.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->assetsBase.'/css/x0.css');
Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerCssFile($this->assetsBase.'/fontello/css/fontello.css', 'screen');
Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerCssFile($this->assetsBase.'/fontello/css/animation.css', 'screen');
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Ifas'=>array('index'),
'Manage',
);
$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'List Ifa', 'url'=>array('index')),
array('label'=>'Create Ifa', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
$('.search-form').toggle();
return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
$('#ifa-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
    data: $(this).serialize()
});
return false;
});
// set up polling at interval
$(function() {
    $.fn.note('poll');
});
");
?>
<style>
i.icon-tag, i.icon-wrench {font-size: 18px;}
</style>
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">Notes (Family Archives)</div>
<div style="float:right; margin-left: 10px;">
<div class="ERR" style="float:left;">
    <input type="radio" name="cls" id="cls3" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[cls]\']').val(3).submit();">
    <label for="cls3">error</label>
</div>
<div class="WAR" style="float:left;">
    <input type="radio" name="cls" id="cls2" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[cls]\']').val(2).submit();">
    <label for="cls2">warning</label>
</div>
<div class="INF" style="float:left;">
    <input type="radio" name="cls" id="cls1" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[cls]\']').val(1).submit();">
    <label for="cls1">info</label> 
</div>
<div class="DBG" style="float:left;">
    <input type="radio" name="cls" id="cls0" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[cls]\']').val(0).submit();">
    <label for="cls0">debug</label>
</div>
<div class="" style="float:left; background-color:#CCCCCC;">
    <input type="radio" name="cls" id="cls" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[cls]\']').val('').submit();">
    <label for="cls">all</label>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float:right; background-color:#CCCCCC; margin-left: 10px;">
    <input type="radio" name="vis" id="vis1" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[vis]\']').val(1).submit();" checked="checked">
    <label for="vis10">visible</label>  
    <input type="radio" name="vis" id="vis0" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[vis]\']').val(0).submit();">
    <label for="vis0">invisible</label>    
    <input type="radio" name="vis" id="vis" onclick="$('.row input[name=\'Ifa[vis]\']').val('').submit();">
    <label for="vis">both</label>  
</div>
<div style="float:right; background-color:#CCCCCC; margin-left: 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="poll" onclick="" checked="checked">
    <label for="poll">polling (<span id="lag">?</span> s)</label>  
</div>
<div style="float:right; background-color:#CCCCCC; margin-left: 10px;        "onclick="$.fn.note('max_id')">
max id <span id="max-id">?</span>
</div>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button', 'style' => 'float:left; font-size: 10px;')); ?>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'ifa-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
    'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->getRowCssClass()',
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'xpl',
    'phpClass',
    'line',
    'function',
    'usr',
    'guessedName',
    'email',
    array(
                'name' => 'cls',
                'visible' => false
            ),
    array(
                'name' => 'vis',
                'visible' => false
            ),
    //'cet',
    //'trace',
    'iconID',
    'albumID',
    'record_created',
    //'timestamp',
    'vrs',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template'=>'{view}{delete}{cet}{trace}',
                    'buttons'=>array
                    (
                        'delete' => array
                        (
                            'click'=>"function(){
                                $(this).note('update', {'vis': 0}).note('remove row');
                                return false;}",
                            'url'=>'"#"',
                            'visible'=> '$data->vis > 0',
                        ),
                        'cet' => array
                        (
                            'label'=>'<i class="icon-tag"></i>',
                            'click'=>"function(){
                                $(this).note('modal cet');
                                return false;}",
                            'url'=>'"#"',
                        ),
                        'trace' => array
                        (
                            'label'=>'<i class="icon-wrench"></i>',
                            'click'=>"function(){
                                $(this).note('modal trace');
                                return false;}",
                            'url'=>'"#"',
                            'visible'=> 'strlen($data->trace) > 0',
                        ),
                    ),
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Comment: current page size = 10 (default). Yes, CGridView shows the latest records first. So that part works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very confusing as you are not describing the problem properly. What are the newest records? do you mean that the list is shown, records are added behind the scene and when navigating through the list does not show the just added records?

The problem might be because the queries are cached. You can put a condition like

```
return array(
            'condition'=>"1<='".time()."'",
        );
```

that would make every query unique so your query will never be cached.

Comment: Yes, indeed that is the problem. Thanks for your reply. If this caching does indeed occur (I am going to try), is that a CGridView feature? Or is this general caching? (I am not aware that I am using any caching; I certainly have never configured any.)

Comment: Not sure where to put this condition. Both `CGridView.condition` and `CSort.condition` are not defined...

Comment: Try adding to your criteria
$criteria->addCondition('1 < :time');
$criteria->params[':time'] = time();

Comment: Yes, it sure looks like that fixed it. Can you perhaps explain where this cache sits? Is it part of CGridView? And why did it refresh correctly when the total # of record was less than 90? (The latter is the reason I thought it could not be caching.)

Comment: I am not sure what is with the 90 records limit, it might have to do with the size of the records. I do think you have caching enabled either in Yii or at MySQL level http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html . I am sure it is not part of CGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Set pagination to false to show all records

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>false,
                    'sort'=>array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
                    ),
    ));
```

To show only new records, this is just like showing unread message in email. So add new field in your table as "is_read" and set as 0 for each record while inserting.

Then once record read (first view), you can set as 1 for "is_read".

In gridview criteria, add a condition to show new records "is_read=0"

Comment: you have changed your question. But, as per your old question, my answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed. Upon re-reading the question was ambivalent. The new phrasing is what I need to know. (I was already aware of turning of pagination.) Are you familiar with the (new) problem?

Comment: Thanks, but that would only defer the problem. The problem is that Yii CGridView fails to load the latest records, once the total record count in my table goes above 90. That should never happen, but it does...

Comment: It's strange. I dont understand your problem. Maybe someother reason cause this issue.